# What differential backup program to use?

Tags: linux, backup, rdiff-backup

Currently I'm using rdiff-backup, but I'm not happy with its performance, and ability to track down the problem.

Is there any other tool that provides differential backups over ssh?

Which is the fastest one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org/) for this. Basically, it's a set of wrapper scripts for [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), which can do incremental backups over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the fastest, but I like duplicity - I've been using it with a wrapper script for a while to do differential backups onto amazon s3, but it can use a lot of different storage backends. Handles things like automatically deleting old backup sets which is quite nice.

Comment: Based on their page, it looks like rdiff-backup + encryption. While I don't object to having encryption, I don't need it, and it doesn't sound like a faster solution.